# How to convert kitchen timer code into a countdown

Tags: arduino-uno, timers

I found this code for a kitchen timer, it was the closest thing to a countdown. The code is here:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

signed short minutes, secondes;
char timeline[16];

void setup() {

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("Chronometre :");


}

void loop() {

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  sprintf(timeline,"%0.2d mins %0.2d secs", minutes, secondes);
  lcd.print(timeline);
  
  delay(1000);
  secondes++;
  
  if (secondes == 60)
  {
    secondes = 0;
    minutes ++;
  }

}
```

How do I convert it properly for it to countdown from 1 minute and 30 seconds?

Comment: How about initializing the time variables `secondes` and `minutes` with the values for 1:30 and then instead of incrementing them decrementing? And of course checking for seconds to be below zero for decrementing the minutes. Have you tried that?

Comment: I didnt know how to initailize that. Could you offer some code?

Comment: You should really do some basic C/C++ and Arduino tutorials, when you want to do Arduino. Otherwise you will not have much fun. Also we are not a free coding service. Look at the code where the mentioned variables are defined. Give each a fitting value by writing an `=` after the name and then the value. In the `loop()` you replace the `++` after the variable names with `--` to decrement them. Then in the if condition `secondes < 0)` and inside the if statement `secondes = 59`. Thats as far as I will go here. With some tutorials and experimenting you will be able to understand that code.

Comment: `I didnt know how to initailize that.`  ... what do you think that line such as `secondes = 0;` does?

Comment: "customize this code i found" is not why we're here. I mean, this is really trivial. Break the problem up into smaller steps and ask for help when you get stuck. Use Serial.println() a lot when you start coding. a lot.

Comment: @chrisl  I know this isn't a free coding service. It was a simple question. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: @JamesChristaldi No, absolutely nothing wrong with asking question. This wasn't to scold you. I just think, that your question leaves basically two ways of answering here: Writing the code for you or giving you a basic C/C++ course. The first one is frowned upon here for some good reasons. The second one is done way better by the many basic C/C++ tutorials/courses on the web. Thus I gave a comment about the needed steps and left it to you to learn the corresponding C/C++ syntax in one of the tutorials/courses.

Comment: But this is Arduino not C/C++

Comment: Right? Am I wrong on that?

Comment: Arduino code is basically C/C++ including `Arduino.h`, which defines the Arduino-related functions like `digitalRead()` and much more. If you're able to program C/C++ programming Arduino will be a lot easier because you understand how to initalize variables, use loops, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start, you need to initalise the `secondes` and `minutes` variables to 30 and 1 respectively.

replace `signed short minutes, secondes;` with:

```
signed short minutes = 1;
signed short secondes = 30;
```

Next thing I notice is that the code you have provided counts up and you have requested that it count down.

Change `secondes++;` and `minutes++;` with:

```
secondes--;
minutes--;
```

Lastly you need to change the logic for when the `secondes` and `minutes` variables reach zero.

If the `secondes` variable reaches zero but the `minutes` variable is greater than zero, then you decrement the minutes (using the line of code provided above) and top-up the `secondes` with 59.

```
secondes = 59;
```

You will need to check the value of the `secondes` and `minutes` variables using a couple of [if](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/if/)...[else](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/else/) statements.

```
if (secondes == 0 && minutes == 0) {
    // insert your timer finished code here
}
else if ( secondes == 0 && minutes > 0) {
    minutes--;
    secondes = 59;
}
else {
    // Error - your code should not reach here.
    // Display an error message on the LCD
}
```

This if..else statement will need to go at the top of your loop instead of the end.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I recommend is that you don't use sprintf(). Your sketch "program storage space" drops from 3502 bytes down to 1928 bytes by NOT using that function call, and dynamic memory used drops from 101 to 79 bytes.

I would recommend an OOP design that would make it easy to add functionality, like the ability to start, stop and reset the timer.

```
// Arduino Uno, IDE version 1.8.9
// 2330 bytes (7%) of program storage space.
// Global variables use 201 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory.
class CountdownTimer{

  private:

    byte m_hour;
    byte m_minute;
    byte m_second;
    byte m_timerActive;
    byte m_timerComplete;
    unsigned long m_previousMillis;

  public:

    CountdownTimer():
      m_hour(0),
      m_minute(0),
      m_second(0),
      m_timerActive(0),
      m_timerComplete(0),
      m_previousMillis(0){}

    bool Update(){

      if(m_hour == 0 && m_minute == 0 && m_second == 0){
        m_timerComplete = 1;
        return 0;
      }

      if(m_timerActive && (millis() - m_previousMillis >= 1000)){
        m_previousMillis += 1000;
        m_second--;
        if(m_second == 255){
          m_second = 59;
          m_minute--;
          if(m_minute == 255){
            m_minute = 59;
            m_hour--;
            if(m_hour == 255){
              m_hour = 0;
            }
          }
        }
        return 1;
      }
      else{
        return 0;
      }
    }

    byte GetIsTimerComplete(){
      return m_timerComplete;
    }

    void SetHour(byte hour){
      m_hour = constrain(hour, 0, 23);
    }

    void SetMinute(byte minute){
      m_minute = constrain(minute, 0, 59);
    }

    void SetSecond(byte second){
      m_second = constrain(second, 0, 59);
    }

    void Start(){
      m_timerActive = 1;
    }

    void Stop(){
      m_timerActive = 0;
    }

    void ReStart(){
      m_timerActive = 1;
      m_timerComplete = 0;
      m_previousMillis = millis();
    }

    void PrintTimeRemaining(){
      if(m_hour < 10){Serial.print("0");}
      Serial.print(m_hour);
      Serial.print(":");
      if(m_minute < 10){Serial.print("0");}
      Serial.print(m_minute);
      Serial.print(":");
      if(m_second < 10){Serial.print("0");}
      Serial.println(m_second);
    }

};

// Make a copy of the object to work with.
CountdownTimer myCountdownTimer;
  
void setup(){

  // Built in pin 13 LED timer completed indicator.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  // Test output to the serial monitor.
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Set the countdown timer values,
  // start the countdown timer and
  // print the initial timer setting.
  myCountdownTimer.SetHour(0);
  myCountdownTimer.SetMinute(1);
  myCountdownTimer.SetSecond(30);
  myCountdownTimer.Start();
  myCountdownTimer.PrintTimeRemaining();
}

void loop(){

  // Call the Update function as fast as possible.
  if(myCountdownTimer.Update()){
    myCountdownTimer.PrintTimeRemaining();
  }

  // Turn on the Uno's Pin 13 LED once timer is complete.
  if(myCountdownTimer.GetIsTimerComplete()){
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  }

}
```