# I have been having a lot of trouble adding a countdown to a piece of code

Tags: programming, arduino-nano, lcd, timers, code-review

This is the code. The /// are where I added the countdown. Unfortunately the countdown only goes down 9 seconds. What I want it to do is go down the full 24 hours. I have been trying to fix this error for months with no luck.

```
int beeper_pin      = 2; //Naming buzzer pin
int resetGarden_pin = 3; //Naming the warning led pin
int pump_pin        = 6; //Naming the pump pin



#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> // Driver Library for the LCD Module

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, A4, A5);

void clearLCDLine(int line)
{
  lcd.setCursor(0, line);
  for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++) // 20 indicates symbols in line. For 2x16 LCD write - 16
  {
    lcd.print(" ");
  }
}







void beepWarning() {            //Makes beeping a subroutine

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("WARNING");
  delay(100);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {

    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("WATER PUMP ACTIVE");
    delay(100);
    clearLCDLine(1);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("WATER PUMP ACTIVE.");
    delay(100);
    clearLCDLine(1);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("WATER PUMP ACTIVE..");
    delay(100);
    clearLCDLine(1);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("WATER PUMP ACTIVE...");
    delay(100);
    clearLCDLine(1);
  }

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("WATER PUMP ACTIVE...");

  for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {   //Repeats 3 times

    digitalWrite(beeper_pin, HIGH); //Turn on buzzer
    delay(100);                     //Delay of 400 milliseconds
    digitalWrite(beeper_pin, LOW);  //Turns off buzzer
    delay(100);                     //Delay of 400 milliseconds

  }
}







void SOSWarning() {            //Makes SOS a subroutine

  clearLCDLine(1);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("WPA Reset Aerogarden");

  for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {   //Repeats 3 times

    for (int d = 0; d < 3; d++) {   //Repeats 3 times
      digitalWrite(beeper_pin, HIGH); //Turn on buzzer
      delay(200);                     //Delay of 400 milliseconds
      digitalWrite(beeper_pin, LOW);  //Turns off buzzer
      delay(200);                     //Delay of 400 milliseconds
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {   //Repeats 3 times
      digitalWrite(beeper_pin, HIGH); //Turn on buzzer
      delay(400);                     //Delay of 400 milliseconds
      digitalWrite(beeper_pin, LOW);  //Turns off buzzer
      delay(400);                     //Delay of 400 milliseconds
    }

    for (int d = 0; d < 3; d++) {   //Repeats 3 times
      digitalWrite(beeper_pin, HIGH); //Turn on buzzer
      delay(200);                     //Delay of 400 milliseconds
      digitalWrite(beeper_pin, LOW);  //Turns off buzzer
      delay(200);                     //Delay of 400 milliseconds
    }

    delay(500);                     //Delay of 500 milliseconds
  }
}







void weekDelay() { //Makes waiting for a week a subroutine
  clearLCDLine(1);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Waiting One Week");





long hour = 23, minute = 59, second = 59;//second //////////////////////////
long countdown_time = (hour * 3600) + (minute * 60) + second; ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  long countdowntime_seconds = countdown_time - (millis() / 1000); /////////
  
  if (countdowntime_seconds >= 0) {   ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    long countdown_hour = countdowntime_seconds / 3600;
    long countdown_minute = ((countdowntime_seconds / 60) % 60);
    long countdown_sec = countdowntime_seconds % 60;
    lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
    if (countdown_hour < 10) {
      lcd.print("0");
    }
    lcd.print(countdown_hour);
    lcd.print(":");
    if (countdown_minute < 10) {
      lcd.print("0");
    }
    lcd.print(countdown_minute);
    lcd.print(":");
    if (countdown_sec < 10) {
      lcd.print("0");
    }
    lcd.print(countdown_sec);
  }
  delay(500);///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////









  delay(500);

  delay(86400000);
  clearLCDLine(0);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Waiting Six Days");
  delay(86400000);
  clearLCDLine(0);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Waiting Five Days");
}








void pumpOn() {               //Makes turning on the pump a subroutine
  clearLCDLine(1);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("PUMPING");
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(pump_pin, HIGH); //Turning on the pump
}








void pumpOff() {              //Makes turning off the pump a subroutine
  digitalWrite(pump_pin, LOW);  //Turning off the pump
  clearLCDLine(1);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("WATER PUMP OFF");
  delay(100);
}








void setup() {
  //run once:
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.init();

  lcd.setCursor(4, 0);//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  lcd.print("HH:MM:SS"); //////////////////////////////////////////////////


  lcd.clear(); // Clear the screen
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Aero_Pump V3");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("By Alex");
  delay(1000);
  pinMode (beeper_pin,      OUTPUT); //Setting outputs
  pinMode (resetGarden_pin, OUTPUT); //Setting outputs
  pinMode (pump_pin,       OUTPUT); //Setting outputs
  lcd.clear(); // Clear the screen


  digitalWrite(resetGarden_pin, LOW); //Turning off the reset garden light


  beepWarning(); //Beeps a warning
  pumpOn();      //Turns on the pump
  delay(3000);  //Adds a delay of 24000 milliseconds
  pumpOff();     //Turns off the pump
  weekDelay();   //Waits a week

  beepWarning(); //Beeps a warning
  pumpOn();      //Turns on the pump
  delay(135000);  //Adds a delay of 48000 milliseconds
  pumpOff();     //Turns off the pump
  weekDelay();   //Waits a week
}







void loop() {

  SOSWarning(); //Beeps an SOS warning
  pumpOn();      //Turns on the pump
  delay(48000);  //Adds a delay of 48000 milliseconds
  pumpOff();     //Turns off the pump

  for (int x = 0; x < 3024000; x++) {
    lcd.backlight(); // turn on backlight.
    delay(100);
    lcd.noBacklight(); // turn off backlight
    delay(100);
  }
  lcd.backlight(); // turn on backlight.
}
```

This is more specifically what needs to be fixed:

```
long hour = 23, minute = 59, second = 49;//second //////////////////////////
long countdown_time = (hour * 3600) + (minute * 60) + second; ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  long countdowntime_seconds = countdown_time - (millis() / 1000); /////////
  
  if (countdowntime_seconds >= 0) {
    long countdown_hour = countdowntime_seconds / 3600;
    long countdown_minute = ((countdowntime_seconds / 60) % 60);
    long countdown_sec = countdowntime_seconds % 60;
    lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
    if (countdown_hour < 10) {
      lcd.print("0");
    }
    lcd.print(countdown_hour);
    lcd.print(":");
    if (countdown_minute < 10) {
      lcd.print("0");
    }
    lcd.print(countdown_minute);
    lcd.print(":");
    if (countdown_sec < 10) {
      lcd.print("0");
    }
    lcd.print(countdown_sec);
  }
```

This is some edited code that I have tried but might have made a mistake on because it does 0 days instead of 7 and (Hours/Min/Sec) 04:09:36.

```
void weekDelay() { //Makes waiting for a week a subroutine
  clearLCDLine(1);
  clearLCDLine(0);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Waiting One Week");


  unsigned long start = millis();
  unsigned long week_secs = 7 * 24 * 3600;
  unsigned long countdowntime_seconds;

  while (countdowntime_seconds = week_secs - (millis() - start)/1000){
     char buff[80];
     unsigned long countdown_day = countdowntime_seconds / 3600 / 24;
     int countdown_hour = (countdowntime_seconds / 3600) % 24;
     int countdown_minute = ((countdowntime_seconds / 60) % 60);
     int countdown_sec = countdowntime_seconds % 60;
     sprintf(buff,"%1d days, %02d:%02d:%02d",
            (int) countdown_day, 
            countdown_hour, 
            countdown_minute,
            countdown_sec
            );
     Serial.print(buff);       
     clearLCDLine(1);
     lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
     lcd.print(buff);      
     delay(1000);
     }
}
```

Comment: You sure have a lot of `delay()`s in your code. Here's a simple `millis` based count down timer if you are interested. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/82217/37523

Comment: It seems like the countdown is just skipped for some reason.

Comment: I would be happy to help you. Before writing any code, it's better to write the `user manual` first. Can you give me a description of your project, what it does, when it does it, etc.?

Comment: Your code is in the middle of the `weekDelay()` function, which looks like it has several problems.  What do you expect `weekDelay()` to do?

Comment: The project is for an Aerogarden. It pumps water into the garden every week from information based on my collected data. It writes on the LCD information like if it is pumping, waiting (it should have the timer here), and it can show when it is going to pump with a beep warning. After beeping, pumping, and waiting for a few times I run out of information and do a loop and show a warning message, blinking the LCD and pumping a set amount.

Comment: WeekDelay() should be a delay for a week. It clears the LCD, Sets the cursor to 0,0 and prints "Waiting one week". It should then have a countdown of 24 hours on the screen and then just how many days it is waiting. It does that through clearing the LCD, Setting the cursor, printing days and waiting.

Comment: Is it supposed to wait a week? As is, `weekDelay` looks like it only does two day-long   `delay(86400000);` pauses.  You could replace lots of its code with `char buff[80]; sprintf(buff,"%02d:%02d:%02d",countdowntime_hour,countdowntime_minute,countdowntime_secs); lcd.print(buff);`
   It also doesn't seem to have any countdown logic--From this code I see no loops in `weekDelay()` that could count down even 9 seconds, let alone the 604800 seconds in a week.

Comment: The answer is very good and seems to work. I do have a question though. How would I make it count down? Sorry for the extra time this will take you. I will give you the checkmark anyways for all the work you did.

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it changed the question too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try something with a `while(){}` loop and a `sprintf()`, like:

```
void weekDelay() { //Makes waiting for a week a subroutine
  unsigned long start = millis();
  unsigned long week_secs = 7 * 24 * 3600;
  unsigned long countdowntime_seconds;

  while (countdowntime_seconds = week_secs - (millis() - start)/1000){
     char buff[80];
     unsigned long countdown_day = countdowntime_seconds / 3600 / 24;
     // or maybe
     //int  countdown_day = (int)(countdowntime_seconds / 3600UL / 24UL);

     int countdown_hour = (countdowntime_seconds / 3600) % 24;
     int countdown_minute = ((countdowntime_seconds / 60) % 60);
     int countdown_sec = countdowntime_seconds % 60;
     sprintf(buff,"%1d days, %02d:%02d:%02d",
            (int) countdown_day, 
            countdown_hour, 
            countdown_minute,
            countdown_sec
            );
     clearLCDLine(1);
     lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
     lcd.print(buff);      
     delay(1000);
     }
}
```

Or make it more general and start it off like:

```
void coundownDelay(unsigned long seconds) { //Makes waiting for a week a subroutine
  unsigned long start = millis();
  unsigned long countdowntime_seconds;

  while (countdowntime_seconds = seconds - (millis() - start)/1000){

     ...

}
```

and call like:

```
  ...
  countdownDelay(7 * 24 * 3600);   //Waits a week
  ...
```

Comment: It is incredibly close and I thank you a lot for your contribution.

Comment: Sorry -- I had the sense of direction wrong.   I edited the math.  For debugging, you might want to try smaller delays so you can see if and where things go wrong in less than 9 hours.

Comment: Ah, it is the integer math interacting with the size of `days`.  04:09:36 = 4*3600+9*60+36 = 14976  which happens to be equal to  7*24*3600 % 32768.     See https://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12146 and https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT35-C.+Use+correct+integer+precisions  for what's happening.   I added some casting and types to the `day=` line.  Alternately, one could define days as `unsigned long days` and then print it with `sprintf(buff,"%1d days, %02lu:%02d:%02d",`

Comment: I changed my code to `int countdown_day =  countdowntime_seconds / 3600 / 24;`   to have two divides instead of a multiply and divide.  I don't have an arduino available, so it is still untested there.  In C, the several versions worked.

Comment: That particular number, 04:09:36 is special, it is 14976 seconds, which is what a week work of seconds (7*24*3600=604800) forced into a signed int that can only hold numbers in −32768, +32767.  This indicating problems doing the math with 16 bit ints.  Right now I can only test code bits with gcc on a Mac, where default math is done with 32 bit ints.  I added two options to the code, one doing the math with unsigned longs all the way through (and casting it to an int for the sprintf) an another attempting to keep the math in ULs and casting it into an int for storage.

Comment: I edited the code at the bottom. This had the same issue unfortunately. I firstly tried to just use the 24UL code and it said that the "countdown day" was not defined. It fixed the issue when I added both pieces of code but that might not have been what you meant when you made the code. Do you want me to define days? Also, I will check the code on a C emulator.

Comment: What emulator do you use? And what was the code you were using for it?